# React native use in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, mobile, react-native

This question is little bit confusing but i need to use React Native in AngularJs.

My requirement is a simple. I am developing website which create Mobile Application without code.(ref: www.ibuildapp.com). For that, I need to display mobile simulator and update mobile application constantly as per user drag and drop action, and last Apk and ipa will gerenate using react native. So in meantime user actions i need to update mobile simulator views so i have to use react native component and my site will be in Angular.

My question is that is it possible to use Angular + react-native simultaneously.
I hope you understand my requirement if need more detail comment me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am also seeking this kind of solution